# How can I set 24 hour time in KDE5

Tags: linux, kde, time, date-time

It seems the new way to set your preferred date format is by country and language.

[image]

[image]

I've never thought about this method but I guess it encourages people to be more multicultural, researching how people around the world like their time displayed. Also, all the months and days get changed to another language so you get to learn those too. Now, I'm all for innovative ideas, but I'm finding it a little challenging to get the exact format I'm after, particularly since I can't see the time format immediately after choosing the dialogue.

[image]

This issue is discussed here: http://kaosx.us/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=966

Really, I just want to know how to set 24 hour time. I guess others might want to set other formats, so how can I know beforehand which country has which time format?

Perhaps we need an application where we could select a time format and it would give you the closest matching country and language, but in the meantime trial and error might be best.

Comment: I'm using KDE 4.8.4, and the route to the setting is similar: System Settings | Locale | Date & Time | Time Format.  It makes no sense to bury the clock display format under Locale, and exclude it from the Digital Clock Settings accessible by right-clicking on the clock.  On mine, if you hover on the pull-down arrow for Time Format, it shows help for how to specify the format (including 24 hr time).

Comment: this may soon be possible... https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=345378#c20

Answer (score 8):

As per the bug that @jozxyqk mentioned, someone pointed out a solution.
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=345378#c26

With `Plasma >= 5.4.0`

```
Right click on clock -> Digital Clock Settings -> Use 24-hour clock.
```

I had the same issue, this fixed it.

---

To enable it globally, I *think* this is how you do it:

1. Go to KDE System Settings
2. Go to Format screen
3. Enable Detailed Settings
4. Select an option that has the 24 hour time format under **Time**.

If you scroll through the list of options, some countries defaulted to 24 hours while others did 12 hour formats, so I'm not quite sure if it's a country-specific default or what. Using `Default (C)` shows the time format I want. Using the US default (or `No change`) used the 12 hour format.

[image: System Settings Format for Time]

Comment: what if I want to set a 24h time format globally, e.g. also for modified-dates in dolphin's list-view?

Comment: @user313032 I'll add that to my answer, thanks!

Comment: @user313032 You could have followed jozxyqk's steps in his question, as that basically what I detailed. +1 to him. (I checked dolphin and it does show modified/created at times with the 24 hour format)

Comment: yes, but it seems slightly nonsensical to have to find a locale with a 24 hour clock by trial and error. Wouldn't it be much better usability-wise, just to be able to directly set 24 hour time somewhere?

Comment: @user313032 I completely agree with you, a checkbox in system settings that enforces it globally would be a huge plus in terms of usability. Maybe there's some details I'm not aware of that would make that difficult to do properly.